# orientation change on iPad messes up touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation

So, I have an iPad app with TabbarController and one ViewController. And the point is that when I enter the app in Portrait orientation and then rotate to the landscape, only 2/3 of the screen receive touches. And what really makes me mad is that this situation happens only in iOS 7 and higher. Please, help me how to solve this issue or tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question makes no sense - perhaps re-read and add in the missing words ?

Comment: Do you use auto layout? I believe you needy to sort the constraints in your storyboard.

Comment: So, your app has a single view controller? I have seen issues on iOS7 when rotating, but that was involving a UITabBarController

Comment: Yes! I do have a tabbar... Sorry for misinforming you. I updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with the UITabBarController discussed over at developer.apple.com. Try doing something like this in your viewcontroller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ...
    [self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
}
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Perfect! Can you please send a link to question on developer.apple.com just to understand why this happens

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped to solve an extremely evil bug. BTW, there is a little reason to set flexible top and bottom margins, setting flexible width & height suffices.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Doesn't hurt to be explicit though.